# SWIFT aws S3 downloads asynchonously ? downloading images and populating a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous, amazon-s3

I m kind of new to swift and IOS and I might have an asynchronous problem (not sure), I have a firebase database giving me the keys and URLS of uploaded content on Amazon S3. I m trying to download the images from S3, store them in an array and then populate the tableview.

The code seems to launch the download but it doesnt progress (a break point on progress doesn t even hit)

could someone give me a hand on how to cleanly populate my tableview ? my array of images is always empty and i don t know if it s coming from my s3 function (but does not return any error) or if it comes from the dispatch events.

```
    //
//  MainWitness.swift
//  trainning2
//
//  Created by Yann MASSARD on 2/2/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Witness. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseUI


class MainWitness: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let rootref = Firebase(url: "XXXXXXX/witness/")
    let refpost = Firebase(url: "XXXXXXX/witness/POSTS")
    var posts = [getitems]()
    var Images = [UIImage]()



    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    // S3 download function / called on view did appear, gets the key from firebase

    func downloadImage(key:String){

        var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadCompletionHandlerBlock?

        let S3BucketName: String = "witnesstest/" + rootref.authData.uid
        let S3DownloadKeyName: String = key


        let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadExpression()
        expression.downloadProgress = {(task: AWSS3TransferUtilityTask, bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64) in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                let progress = Float(totalBytesSent) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToSend)
                print("Progress is: \(progress)")
            })
        }

        completionHandler = { (task, location, data, error) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                if ((error) != nil){
                    print("Failed with error")
                    print("Error: \(error!)")
                }
                else{
                    //Set your image
                    self.Images.append(UIImage(data: data!)!)
                }
            })
        }

        let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.defaultS3TransferUtility()

        transferUtility.downloadToURL(nil, bucket: S3BucketName, key: S3DownloadKeyName, expression: expression, completionHander: completionHandler).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in
            if let error = task.error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            if let exception = task.exception {
                print("Exception: \(exception.description)")
            }
            if let _ = task.result {
                print("Download Starting!")     // shows in console for each firebase post loop
            }
            return nil;
        }

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        // [1] Call the queryOrderedByChild function to return a reference that queries by the "author" property
         self.refpost.queryOrderedByChild("author").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

            var newItems = [getitems]()

            for item in snapshot.children {

                let postitem = getitems(snapshot: item as! FDataSnapshot)
                newItems.append(postitem)

            //     READ IMAGE FROM S3
                self.downloadImage(postitem.imagekey)

            }

            self.posts = newItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
       //ref.unauth()
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //tableview datasource and delegate
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        // is any user log ?
        if ((rootref.authData) != nil) {
            print("user logged")
        } else {
            print("user not logged")
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("log", sender: self)

            }
        }

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1

    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: MainWitnessTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RIcell") as! MainWitnessTableViewCell

            // populate the cell
            let postitem = posts[indexPath.row]
            cell.postOwner.text = postitem.author
            cell.postContent.text = postitem.content
            cell.postDate.text = postitem.createon

           // cell.cellImage.image = Images[indexPath.row] // returns array index out of range


        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return posts.count



    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a few months old, but just in case you're still having trouble I'll give my two cents.

It looks to me the trouble is determining when to refresh your table cells (assuming all your calls to get keys from Firebase and data from S3 are working fine; if they aren't, consider writing some unit tests or using a playground to make sure you can get data correctly outside the context of a view controller, it will be faster).

After you get your Firebase references, you are calling `self.downloadImage(postitem.imagekey)`, and then `self.tableView.reloadData()`. Since `downloadImage` is asynchronous, you probably won't have any image data yet when you reload the table, so that could be why you don't seem to have anything. Your table reload must be called after you've populated your `images` array from S3.

Here is how I would go about doing it:

1. Your `posts` and `images` arrays are both tied together; why not create a struct called `Posts` which contain parameters `postInfo: getitems` and `image: UIImage?`, where you may or may not have an image for that post? Then your data model for the tableView will be `var data: [Posts]`. The image parameter for each `Post` is nil until it has been loaded from S3.
2. `viewDidLoad`: Begin the query to Firebase for the posts and their image keys.
3. In the Firebase call's callback, if you get back X posts, you can say your tableView's data model contains X posts. Append each post to your array `data: [Post]` and set the `.image` parameter as nil since you don't have any images yet. Once all the posts have been appended, you can reload the tableView.
4. In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, if the image at `data[indexPath.row].image` is `nil`, you can put in a temporary placeholder UIImage to show until the real image has loaded from S3. If `data[indexPath.row].image` is not nil, set the actual image.
5. Start downloading the S3 images (you can still do that for each post in your Firebase call's callback) and update your array `data: [Post]` every time you get an image back. For each image you get back, reload that table cell only. This will call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` again. Since the `.image` parameter will no longer be nil, you will see an actual image replace the placeholder image.

Here is how you can efficiently update just a particular row instead of reloading the entire table:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

If you are storing a many large UIImages in your array you may have memory problems and might want to look at keeping an image cache and loading images a few indices ahead of when you'd scroll them onto the screen rather than loading all the images at once.